# Alphatab tutorial won't load Guitar Pro files

Tags: javascript, tabs, loading, notation, guitar

I just discovered AlphaTab and did the tutorial for the web. This seemed to work fine for loading the "Canon Rock" file but I can't get it to load any of my GP files, from old to new. They are loaded fine on the AlphaTab home page but not with the tutorial. The only thing I tried was to change the settings from the Canon Rock file to my local file. Is there something else that needs to be done. Thanks for any help.

I tried gp3, gp5, gp and mxl files and got Page Loading messages but the file would never render the notation.